# CSS animation - several circles radiating from centre

Tags: css, animation

I will try my best to describe, hopefully this makes sense...

I want to have several circles on top of each other, then using css animation, I would like the circles to follow a half circle/elipse path away from the centre at different angles finishing in a circle of circles around the starting point...

I have figured out how to get an animation to "Orbit" a central point but I cant find a way to change the angle of the orbit.

```
@keyframes curveBall {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg) translateX(150px);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg) translateX(150px);
  }
}
```

I have thought of creating several orbits that all intersect in the middle but orbit away in different directions, then getting the orbits to start at the intersection and then only perform a part of the orbit but I still cant figure out how to get it to work. Any help would be appreciated, Thanks.

EDIT: Here is a Demo which kind of shows where I am trying to get to
http://dabblet.com/gist/f30d86cebe9790faadf6

Comment: A demo is really going to help here...at the moment it's hard to understand how this should look.

Comment: If you're going to be animating multiple object I'd suggest that javascript is **much** more suited to doing the calculating for you.

Comment: I have been thinking that Paulie_D, I was trying to branch out and use CSS animation as I havent used it too much. Maybe I will save it for something simpler.

Comment: And yeah a demo would have been good but probably more confusing as I cant even get it close to what I want it to do :)

Comment: I added a demo of something that is kind of what I am after but I want it more uniform and up to 8 "Balls"